# How to set the transparency of the entire row to 0.5?

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor, transparent

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[right=0.5in, left=0.5in, top=0.78in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}

\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}

\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.42}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\arrayrulecolor{gray!40}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}
\centering
\scalebox{4}{
\begin{tabular}{|=c|+c|+c|+c|+c|+c|}
\rowcolor[gray]{0.65}\multicolumn{6}{c}{ \textcolor{white}{\scriptsize Meditation} \vspace*{0.2cm}}\\
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}}
\rowstyle{\transparent{0.5}} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}}7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}}13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}}19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\ 
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}}25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want to change the transparency of the entire row to 0.5. Here I'm able to replace the color gray of the row but unable to set the transparency for the each element of the row. Above code works for only first elment.

Comment: please shorten your example. There is no need to add irrelevant stuff like special fonts.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I have modified the code. I think \transparent is not working anymore here. And it will take me so long to write \transparent infront of each element of the table.

Comment: You might be better off with a TikZ based tabular, such as tabulararry.

Answer (score 3):

you can only set one of your `\rowstyle` per row, as you overwrite the internal definition. So you need to combine the commands: `\rowstyle{\color{gray}\transparent{0.5}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}

\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}

\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\@rowstyle}%
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.42}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\arrayrulecolor{gray!40}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|=c|+c|+c|+c|+c|+c|}
\rowcolor[gray]{0.65}\multicolumn{6}{c}{ \textcolor{white}{\scriptsize Meditation} \vspace*{0.2cm}}\\
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}\transparent{0.5}}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
\hline
\rowstyle{\color{gray}}7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please do not ask unrelated questions in comment. That pings only me. Ask a new question then other can help you too.

Comment: Is it possible to center the text 'Meditation' vertically?